# Finding g(n) in a recursively defined algorithm[HOMEWORK]

Tags: algorithm, recursion, logic

I've been asked to find

```
g(1), g(2), g(3), if g(n) is defined recursively by 

g(0) = 2 for n = 0

g(n + 1) = g(n) + 2 for n = 1,2,3
```

I've looked through the lecture slides that I have been given but cannot find any examples that might help me. I have no idea where to start and can't find any good instructions online either. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful, Thanks!

Comment: What do you need help with? The Recurrence Relation? Recursion? or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g(n+1) = g(n) + 2 {for n = 1,2,3}
```

using this:

```
g(1) = g(0) + 2
```

but `g(0) =2`
therefore  `g(1) =2+2 = 4`

similarly `g(2) = g(1) + 2 = 4+2=6`
and `g(3) = g(2) + 2 = 8`

Hope this helps